# C No memory available to program: unsafe to call malloc error

Tags: c, performance, memory

I am trying to create all of the matrices from size 10x10 to 1000x1000 around 980 I start running out of memory even though the program is clearly not using all 4GB of my system.  My code looks like:

```
    double **a3;
    double **result;
    a3 = malloc(k * sizeof(double *));
    for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        a3[i] = malloc(sizeof(double));
    }
    result = malloc(k * sizeof(double *));
    for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        result[i] = malloc(k * sizeof(double));
    }
    for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        for( j = 0; j < k; j++)
        {
            a3[i][j] = 0;
            result[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    ...
    for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    free(a3[i]);
    free(result[i]);
}
free(a3);
free(result);
```

I am not sure why this doesn't work (it does work if I use int arrays but I need double arrays)

I am using Mac OSX 64bit

Comment: you won't be able to malloc 4GB; probably closer to 2GB. What OS? Winows? Linux?

Comment: what's the value of `k`?

Comment: k goes from 10 to 1010 but 980 is when it fails.  I am on Mac OSX

Comment: Though my used memory goes from 2.21 GB to 2.24GB (so it's using .03GB) so there has to be something I am missing in the malloc call

Comment: 10 - 1000 requires 2.6 GB of memory with `double`. And half that for `int`.

Comment: There may be some sort of heap fragmentation issue going on. Try reversing the loop so that k goes from 1010 down to 10.

Comment: How does your program fail, is it segfaulting?  Because you are improperly accessing your data here: a3[i][j] = 0; You can't use double array index to access the buffer you got from a3[i] = malloc

Comment: On linux I get segment fault on macNo memory available to program now: unsafe to call malloc.  Is there any way to use malloc on a 2d array?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how 'clear' you actually are about not using all the memory *that's available to your program*. If I'm figuring rightly, you end up allocating a total of 333,833,185 doubles. At eight bytes each, that's over 2.5GB.

Not sure how much is available to your C compiler's memory management facilities... why not write a simple program that discovers what the biggest amount of memory you could malloc() is?